# How to sync the dubbed audio to make a dual audio .avi

Tags: audio, sync

I have a show with the original audio, XviD encoded with mp3 in a .avi. The local TV has started broadcasting the show with the dubbed audio. I captured some of the shows off of the TV broadcast, demuxed them and got .mp2 of the dubbed audio. Now I want to include this dubbed audio within the original files I previously had. I know how to include it as the second audio stream within the .avi, But first I need to sync the dubbed audio with the original video as it was a bit different when broadcast by TV, i.e. there were some censored, cut parts in it so the dubbed audio needs to have some editing (the ads were also recorded) etc. and not just some delay to get in sync with the video. On the other hand, the original video comes in 23.976 fps whereas the dubbed audio was extracted from the TV broadcast which is 25.000 fps.

So is there any application to see the video with while editing the dubbed audio at the same time so that I can get it in sync, delete some parts, etc. And how can I change the fps of the dubbed audio or the original file (whichever would be more reasonable to do) to have them both in the same fps.

Would be great if I could do all these without any quality loss as the audio is of bad quality as it is.

I'd be very grateful if you could help me with this.

Comment: Audio isn't rated by "fps". What matters is the total length, measured in hours, minutes, seconds and samples or mSec. So the fact that the off-air video is at 25 fps makes no difference.

Comment: My main issue is cut parts of the dubbed video. I can handle different "fps"

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but you can do what you want with any decent video editing application. Have you tried it and it didn't work?